# Are $x\in \mathbb{R}$ and $-\infty <x<+\infty$ indicating the same meaning in mathematics?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, education

I would like to know if it is possible in mathematics to express    $x\in \mathbb{R}$ by $-\infty <x<+\infty$ in other way : Are  $x\in \mathbb{R}$ and $-\infty <x<+\infty$  indicating  the same meaning in mathematics  ?

Thank you for any help

Comment: What do you mean by writing $-\infty <x<\infty$, if not that $x$ is already thought as a real number?

Comment: @DietrichBurde E.g. Matt's answer, or Bernard's comment on my answer: $x\in\mathbb{Q}$, or $x\in\mathbb{Z}$, or etc. (Or, as in my answer, $x$ in some weird ordered ring which is not $\mathbb{R}$.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $x$ is a real number, then the two statements are the same. The latter could also be used if $x$ were assumed to be, for example, an integer or rational number, as well as in some more exotic totally ordered sets in advanced topics.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, these two expressions mean the same thing in every context I can imagine. (I'm sure there is *some* context where they mean different things - e.g. if one is considering an Archimedean ring with infinitesimal elements strictly containing $\mathbb{R}$, augmented by new elements "$+\infty$" and "$-\infty$" - but such a context would have to be specified at the outset, and I have not actually seen such a context before.) Certainly, **unless explicitly specified otherwise** the two expressions mean the same thing.

EDIT: A more realistic alternate use of the notation would be if $x$ were already specified to be a rational number, or an algebraic number, or an integer, or . . . Now, in these cases, $x$ is still real, so it's not quite a counterexample to what you ask, but it's worth noting.

Comment: @DietrichBurde Actually, in my answer I specify a context where it could have meaning and still refer to non-real $x$. Did you actually read my answer?

Comment: What about the context where $x\in \mathbb{Z}$. The inequality is then true but is not equivalent to $x\in \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @BernardMasse That's an even better one, although I still haven't seen that notation used that way; I've added it.

Comment: @DietrichBurde Note that Bernard provides another (and much more plausible) such context.

Comment: No, I think the OP means this differently. An integer is a real number anyway. He wants to say that the inequality means that $x$ is real - which is clear (OK, except for your Archimedian ring), perhaps, but that is not so convincing).

Comment: @DietrichBurde Ah, I agree. Still, the first part of my answer describes a way in which that expression could be used to refer to a non-real $x$. So it's not a vacuous question.

Comment: Noah, I agree, and I find your answer instructive, I just did not quite understand, what the question really is.